# Deep link problem on a Android 12 Pixel 6

Tags: android, kotlin, android-deep-link

My app on the following device won't auto-verify the domain, I need to turn it on from the app settings manually.

```
Device Make: Google
Model: Pixel 6
Android OS Version: 12
Build number: SQ3A.220605.009.A1
```

The weird thing about this is that the deep link is working fine on other devices, the [google tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) is even throwing a success response and even verified using the `adb shell pm get-app-links [MY-PACKAGE-NAME]`  command.

The same behavior continued after the device was factory reset.

Here is the manifest intent filter

```
           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="${host}" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/path-prefix" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Any ideas why it is not working on the mentioned specific device?